# Method(s) to quantify the hysteresis of a data set

Tags: references, methodology, method-comparison

I have a data set for two different mixtures of a material with 5 and 6 samples in each data set. I would like to quantify the hysteresis each sample in a "generally accepted" way. The following is my data set,

[image]

Below is an example of one of the data sets. This is a data set that has a high amount of hysteresis, as shown by the area inside its "loop". I have also annotated the direction of travel for the data and how I could connect the two ends if needed.

[image]

I am currently thinking of connecting the data sets at the bottom and finding the area inside the newly formed loop, however, I am not sure if this is the best approach. I would greatly appreciate any reference is possible.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to CV. I feel your question can be significantly improved so as to attract attention and possibly good answers. What is your formal definition of hysteresis? What is your measure of hysteresis with respect to these data? What do you mean by loop? What do you mean by "data set at the bottom"? Can you give a citation or two of research measuring hysteresis as you define it? What prevents you from using such "generally acceptable" methods in your field of work? If you click the "edit" link at the lower left you can edit your question to clarify.

Comment: I consider the hysteresis to demonstrated by the fact that the y  data changes depending on the direction of the x data.  I think this is the general idea of hysteresis. I do not have a standard method for quantifying the hysteresis is my field, so, therefore, I am trying to track down methods that can be used to quantify the hysteresis in this data set.

Comment: Can you say a bit more about "y data changes depending on the direction of the x data"? That sounds simply like regression (i.e. some flavor of $y = f(x) + \varepsilon$), but maybe you mean something more specific? Also: are your data serial? (Seems from the way both data sets are connected that this may be the case.)

Comment: @Alexis, see the changes made to the original post. I hope this clears up a few issues.

Comment: Yes! Big improvement. And a smaller area means "more hysteresis," or something close to that? Also: data set 1 has five loops, and data set 2 has 4, correct? If so, I think you want a separate measure of hysteresis in each loop, with loops "nested" in data sets for analysis (... but that's not your question :). How does the fact that a loop may mostly have a tiny area *except* that the start and end points differ widely affect the meaning of your measure?

Comment: Generally, as least as I understand it, something with a high hysteresis will have a large area inside the curve, while something with a low hysteresis will have a smaller area inside the curve. Therefore, looking at my data set 1 will have a much lower hysteresis than that of data set 2.  The remainder of your questions are very well formulated, however, these would be dependent on the method I use to quantify the hysteresis.  I think the question of quantifying the hysteresis would be easier if the data sets always came back to zero, but this is not the data I have.

Comment: What is the nature of Y? Can it be negative? In general, what are X  Y here?

Comment: Sure, I am looking for a general way to quantify the hysteresis, however, I am starting to realize that this is not as standardized as I thought.